# React Native: Google-text-to-speech (tts) doesn't work well

Tags: android, react-native, google-text-to-speech

I have a react-native mobile app that pronounces words with google tts. But it doesn't work after the fortieth pronunciation. After exiting the application and re-entering it, it starts working. I think this is related to google tts api. How can I solve it?

Comment: Hello, could you please provide the code where you are calling the TTS API within your application?

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz  Yes, From this documantion:            
                                                                                    
https://www.netguru.com/blog/react-native-text-to-speech

Comment: It works fine in expo but not in react native cli

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz my codes : https://ibb.co/KD9HHmj    https://ibb.co/fHWYXWW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "speech.release()" code:

```
    const speech = new Sound(voice, '', (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.warn('failed to load the sound', error)
    
        return
      }
      speech.play((success) => {
        if (!success) {
          console.warn('playback failed due to audio decoding errors')
        }else{
          speech.release()  // Need to add this code
        }
      })
      return 
    })
```